# expected string or buffer

Tags: python, sql, ubuntu, web-crawler

I am writing a crawler which crawls and save the crawled information in variable `i`, so I did this:

```
my_string = i
match = re.search("\<!-- populate table from mysql database -->(.*?)\</tbody>" , my_string).group(1)    
print match
```

Got this error:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

Can anyone give me advice on what's the problem here?

Comment: `i` is not a string (or buffer) ..what does `i` contain? Try: `my_string = str(i)`

Comment: the information i crawled from a demo website table

Comment: actually i tried the first comment and it worked already thks !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_string` i.e. `i` is not a string (or buffer) needed by `re.search`.

You can convert it to a string and then do `re.search`:

```
my_string = str(i)
match = re.search(r"\<!-- populate table from mysql database -->(.*?)\</tbody>" , my_string).group(1)
```